# Trouble with the google api client. It does not want to read a variable as a list in the body section

Tags: python

Why am I getting an error on the batch update line?

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import pandas as pd

```
# Authenticate into Target worksheet
# Provide the right methods from google and the right scopes (app services)
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'keys.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

# The ID for the target spreadsheet.
TARGET_WORKBOOK = 'xxx'

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

sheet_id = 2083229665

# Build the service object for the Google Sheets API
service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

# Load the DataFrame
data = [['Name', 'Age'], ['Alice', 25], ['Bob', 30],['steve','55'], ['gayle','54']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

datalist = df.values.tolist()


# Define the range of the data
range_ = 'ExpenseLog!A1:' + chr(ord('A') + len(df.columns) - 1) + str(len(df)) 


# Define the request body Execute the request
requests = []

for i, row in enumerate(datalist):
# Format the row values into the proper structure
    values = [{'userEnteredValue': {'stringValue': cell}} for cell in row]

# Create the updateCells request for the current row

    request = {
        'updateCells': {
            'range': {
                'sheetId' : sheet_id,
                'startRowIndex': i,
                'endRowIndex': i + 1,
                'startColumnIndex': 0,
                'endColumnIndex': len(row)
                },
            'rows': [
                {
                'values': values
                }
                ],
             'fields': 'userEnteredValue'
            }
        }
# Append the request to the list of requests
requests.append(request)

# Perform the batch update
result = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=TARGET_WORKBOOK, 
        body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

I've seen several attempts at describing this but they all seem to think that having requests as a list in the body section will work, but it doesn't seem to be.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

100's of print statements later and everything seems to have the values, but they are not getting read when used in the last line of the code.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: Thanks for the support. I am trying to upload a matrix of data (almost 5000 rows and 36 columns) to a google spreadsheet using a batch update process. It errors out after about 70 lines when I try to use the simple upload call.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `It errors out after about 70 lines when I try to use the simple upload call.`, unfortunately, from your reply and your question, I couldn't understand the detailed error. I apologize for this.